# how to get static files in Flask without url_for('static', file_name='xxx')

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, static-files

I don't want use  url_for('static', file_name='foo.jpg') to get static file in template.

how to get static file in this way:

```
<img src="/pic/foo.jpg" />
```

thanks

Comment: As long as `/pic/foo.jpg` exists it should work fine. Did you try it?

Comment: Just from curiosity - why don't want to use? :)

Comment: @Cfreak thank you , it's works fine. i write the wrong path before.

Comment: @IgnasB. i think common path more convenient and intuitive for FE, what's your point

Comment: @Robin, well just asked :) I thought maybe you spotted some performance issue or something. I always prefer to have dynamic things, just in case I will change static dir to another or smth, so I don't ned to worry then about the some time ago created template which I already forgot to exist :) But this is everyone's choice ;)

Comment: i've just had the same problem and solved it like that:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29521067/303114

Comment: i just had a similar issue and i solved like that:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29521067/303114 notice it's quite similar to what i_4_got is suggesting just using add_url_rule method instead of the route

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set up your own route to serve static files.  Add this method and update the static path directory in the `send_from_directory` method, then your img tag should work.

```
@app.route('/pic/<path:filename>')
def send_pic(filename):
    return send_from_directory('/path/to/static/files', filename)
```

For a production app, you should set up your server to serve static files directly.  It would be much faster and use less server resources, but for a few users the difference shouldn't be a problem.