# Having html pages and a flask application on the server

Tags: python, flask

I have a situation where i have a lot of html files and a flask application on other side which will be running on the server.
I want to configure server in such a way that html file is displayed when i go to www.example.com and flask application is called to render pages www.example.com/app

Here i have huge data to display on the website and the other flask app is used for customer specific. 
I cannot have @app.route for thousands of html pages to render that particular page. So now i want to configure my web server where html files are accessed when i go to my website and it says away from the flask application and flask application is called when i go to app.

Thanks

Comment: What server are you using? Nginx? Apache?

Comment: Im currently using Apache Server.

Comment: What method of deploying flask are you looking at mod_wsgi?

Comment: WSGIScriptAlias /donut /path/to/code/wsgi.py

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask

Comment: I am using gunicorn with WSGI