# How do I use a flat Flask directory hierarchy?

Tags: python, flask

The file `index.html` is static, and hence it would be wasteful to pass it through `render_template()`. If I [store `index.html` under `static/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24578419/704972)
and use `app = Flask(__name__)`, all is well.

But if I point `static_url_path=''` to the root and keep `index.html` in the same folder as the Python app, I get

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Nov/2016 14:35:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello, World!</h2>
</body>
```

**.py**

```
from flask import Flask, current_app
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return current_app.send_static_file('index.html')

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

How do I use a fully flat directory hierarchy, keeping the two files above in the same directory?

Comment: I would discourage you from serving static pages through Flask if that's all you need to do.

Look into `static_folder`, instead of `static_url_path`.

See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20648053/3261863) for `send_from_directory`, which may be of use to you, as you don't need to clobber your static settings to serve one-off pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `static_folder` rather than `status_url_folder` and specify the absolute path of the folder rather than just a blank string.

You can view the default static folder path with `print(app.static_folder)`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`flask.send_file()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.send_file):

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return flask.send_file('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```