# What is the simplest way to host sphinx documentation (static html) on a local network?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, webserver, python-sphinx

I would like to host sphinx documentation on a local network for a python application I am writing.

I have unsuccessfully tried to host it using the following Flask methods:

1. [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)
2. [Flask: How to serve static html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578330/flask-how-to-serve-static-html)

The above methods either resulted in a 404 or unformatted html (no css, etc)

I've also tried using a simple [http server such as python](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255) from within the docs/_build/html/ directory (where index.html exists) and only a 404 was achieved.

How can I host this documentation for my local network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply serve the files using a web server like Apache or Nginx. Some file repository systems can let you browse static sites (Artifactory, for example).  You could also use readthedocs.org