# Jinja2 render multiple html files?

Tags: python, html, templates, flask, jinja2

I have main `index.html` file and it contains several links to sub-html files. For example, from `index.html` if an user clicks an link it directs to sub-page `intro.html` but seems like `render_template` only receives one `html` file. How do I connect multiple html files using `render_template`?

---

Files structures:
    templates/
        index.html
        text.html

I just want to link `text.html` file from `index.html`.

In the `index.html`, I will have a link like the following:

```
<a href="text.html">Link</a>
```

Then I want to direct the `Link` to load the contents of `text.html`

---

Second edit

```
@app.route('/myhtml', methods=['GET'])
def myhtml():
    return render_template('myhtml.html')
```

I want to to something like this.
If I type `localhost:8000/myhtml`  it should link to `myhtml.html`

Comment: ```render_template``` only renders one template at a time and it makes sense. In your template you either want to serve static files or you want to call a view function which in turn will render it's corresponding template. Which one do you want to do?

Comment: what do you mean by `view` function? I just want to separate html files and serve them all in one localhost

Comment: Put a sample code then I can help you more. By view I mean the function which your request will be routed to.

Comment: I added an example. Thanks!

Comment: As I see you only want to serve static html files, for that reason you should use webserver not flask. Anyway flask has some methods for these. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20648053

Comment: I want to to something like this.
If I type `localhost:8000/myhtml`  it should link to `myhtml.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy-- you just need to capture the file you're requesting from the url, then use that to look up an existing template:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, abort
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'page': 'index'})
@app.route('/<page>')
def html_lookup(page):
    try:
        return render_template('{}.html'.format(page))
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If you just try to access `127.0.0.1:5000` it'll default the `page` variable to `index` and therefore will try and `render_template('index.html')` whereas if you try `127.0.0.1:5000/mypage` it will instead search for `mypage.html`.

If it fails, it'll abort with a 404 not found error.

This example, totally cribbed from the [simple blueprint example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/#my-first-blueprint) in the Flask documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html file use this:

```
<a href="/about">Link</a>
```

And then you need a corresponding route that looks like this:

```
@app.route('/about')
def about_page():

    # Do something else here

    return render_template('text.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```