# Flask, Keep getting 404 serving static files using send_static_file

Tags: python, flask

I followed the instructions from [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask), but still couldn't get it working.

Here's my project structure:

```
Project_path  
 |
 +--app
 |  |
 |  +--main.py
 +--static
    |
    +--js
       |
       +--jquery-1.11.2.min.js
```

Here's `main.py`:

```
@app.route('/js/<path:path>')
def serve_static(path):
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
    print(os.path.join(root_dir, 'static', 'js', path))
    return app.send_static_file(os.path.join(root_dir, 'static', 'js', path))
```

Here's `index.html`:

```
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  ...
```

And when I visit `/`, I could see the correct path of javascript file printed on the screen
which is `Project_path/static/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js`.

But still, I got

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2014 11:26:30] "GET /js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
After stepping through the `send_static_file` method, I find out what's going on. Basically, I shouldn't use abspath as argument, flask has a judgement in `send_static_file`:

```
if os.path.isabs(filename) or \
   filename == '..' or \
   filename.startswith('../'):
    raise NotFound()
```

And since the `filename` I passed into is a abspath, flask raise `NotFound()`.
It seems that what it supposed to be passed in is a relative path to `self.static_folder`(self is `<Flask 'main'>`), which, in my project, is `Project_name/app/static`. However, I didn't set `static_folder` myself which means flask thinks the static folder should be there.

I'm still trying to figure out what to do.

Comment: Why are you going through all this? Flask will automatically serve static files. You don't need to write a view for it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Not quite true. flask serves static files automatically if 1. set src="/static/js/xxx.js"; 2. static folder is in the same directly with `app.py`.

Comment: for me this one worked :                                             @app.route('/static/<path:filename>')
def serve_static(filename):
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(root_dir, 'static', 'js'), filename)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Finally got it working. use **[`flask.send_from_directory`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_from_directory)**

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/js/<path:filename>')
def serve_static(filename):
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(root_dir, 'static', 'js'), filename)
```

It is now clear to me that flask really hate people putting `app.py` or in my case `main.py` into a subdirectory. **Use `send_static_file` only if your static folder is what flask thinks to be, i.e. a folder with name `static` in the same directory with app.py**.

Comment: you can replace root_dir with **'.'** - `return send_from_directory(os.path.join('.', 'static', 'js'), filename)`

Comment: This answer is not completely true. For blueprints you can set another static folder and this static folder could be with any name.

Comment: Dear future me: Careful when passing a _relative_ path as the first argument to `send_from_directory`. It will NOT be interpreted relative to the current working directory, if that is what you are after.

Answer (score 19):

All you need to do is, pass the [`static_folder` parameter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#application-object) to the initiator:

> `static_url_path` – can be used to specify a different path for the
>   static files on the web. Defaults to the name of the `static_folder`
>   folder.
>
> `static_folder` – the folder with static files that should be served at
>   static_url_path. Defaults to the 'static' folder in the root path of
>   the application.

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=os.path.abspath('/foo/bar/zoo/'))
```

Now, flask will look for a directory named `static` in `/foo/bar/zoo` from where to serve static files. You only use `send_from_directory` if you are serving *media* files which may not be in the same location as static files.

Comment: What is the correct `static_url_path` for my project? And what should be the `src` attribute in html?

Comment: Its the fully qualified path to the parent directory of `static`, and you don't need to make any changes in your src attribute, it will be exactly as in the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#static-files).

Comment: So it's `static_url_path=Project_path/static/` and `src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"`, correct?

Comment: No, remove the `static` part, and please read the documentation which explains it a lot better than I can in these comments.

Comment: After many tests, I'm sure that if I want to put static files in seperate folders(css, js, ...), it's not possible to serve them only by modifying `static_url_path` and `static_folder`. Using `url_for` in jinja2 would work but that's another story.

Comment: thanks, took a while to find this solution with `os.path.abspath()`

Comment: When do we use app.send_static_file over render_template?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `'static'` in the last `os.path.join` in the `return` clause.

Comment: I thought you are correct, but after adding `static`, it still gives me 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

for me this one worked :

```
@app.route('/static/<path:filename>')
def serve_static(filename):
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(root_dir, 'static', 'js'),   filename)
```

beside adding this script into init

```
app._static_folder = os.path.abspath("static/")
app = Flask(__name__)
```

into `__init__.py`

Comment: i also call static files in my HTML code in this way : <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/homestyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of 404 error for pages you just added (even if programmed correctly), is if you have previous versions of the script (.py file) still running: make sure to close out and end (terminate) the process.