# Flask not serving static files

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

My static files are all returning a 404 error.

below is the structure:

```
-root
   -web
      -static
        -css
          -main.css
      -templates
         base.html
         home.html

      app.py
```

I have a static and templates folder in the same directory as the app. Below is the code for app.py:

```
class FrontEnd(Flask):
    jinja_options = Flask.jinja_options.copy()
    jinja_options.update(dict(
        block_start_string='{%',
        block_end_string='%}',
        variable_start_string='[[',
        variable_end_string=']]',
        comment_start_string='{#',
        comment_end_string='#}',
    ))

app = FrontEnd(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index_page():
    details = {"name" : "mark", "surname" : "boleigha", "occupation" : "programmer"}
    view_data = { "page_name" : "this is the homepage", "title" : "Home", "details" : details }
    return render_template("home.html", **view_data)
```

below is the code for base.html:

```
   <head>
       <title>[[title]] | Recruitr</title>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="[[ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') ]]"  />
   </head>
   <body>
      {% block content %}

      {% endblock content %}
   </body>
</html>
```

below is the code for home.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  #body here
{% endblock content %}
```

please note that i use [[ in the jinja templates to avoid confusions with curly braces as i intend to use a javascript framework.

All CSS files are in static folder. Template render but without styling as  static files are suddenly returning 404 error.

everything was working fine until i rebooted. below is screenshot of my terminal and file tree:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a0fJ.png)

[file_tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0obH.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask, Keep getting 404 serving static files using send\_static\_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596297/flask-keep-getting-404-serving-static-files-using-send-static-file)

Comment: Do you have configured Flask to serve static files or any nginx/apache/… proxy to do it instead? From what we can read here anything that is not `your-domain.tld/` will result in a 404 error.

Comment: We have no idea on where your static files are, and what URL Flask is seeing from you. Please provide additional information.

Comment: Please show your html as well

Comment: i have edited to show the directory structure

Comment: Still it's not clear about your director structure. In your index_page returns `home.html` but where is home.html in your modified question? I suggest you to take screenshot of your ide folder and file tree view, Then attache it here. Also it will be great if you add your home.html and base.html and screenshot of your terminal. Thanks

Comment: i have added and done all asked. please help. it is driving me nuts

Comment: Are you missing the "web" folder?