# Is it portable to use os.getcwd() in a web (Flask) app?

Tags: flask

In a `templates/index.html` file I can write

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href={{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}>
```

and `url_for` retrieves the CSS file from a static folder just fine (FWIW, notwithstanding that `css/main.css` has a forward slash on Windows).

I would like to open a static file `static/number.txt`, read one number from it, and display that number.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def number():
    filename = url_for('static', filename='txt/number.txt')
    with open(filename) as f:
        number = next(f)
    return render_template('index.html', number=number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**static/txt/number.txt**

```
2345
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<body>
    {{ number }}
</body>
```

For this simple example, I am not attempting to optimize by running [Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20648053/9295807)
and IIUC this simple task requires neither [`send_from_directory()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27598141/9295807)
nor [`os.getcwd()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38338725/9295807)
. There is also no need to tinker with `app.static_folder` nor to be worried about the folder separator by using `os.join.path()` (I happen to be on Windows, but ideally this should be invisible in the code). There is also no need to modify the default [`static`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26554578/9295807)
folder.

The code above gives me

```
c:\read-static>python app.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda3\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  ...
  File "app.py", line 10, in number
    with open(filename) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/txt/number.txt'
127.0.0.1 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

What am I missing? Should I be using `os.getcwd()` to read a static file in Flask? Something in relying on `os.getcwd()` seems unpalatable/hackish.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
import os
```

and replacing the `url_for(...)` line with:

```
filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'static', 'txt', 'number.txt')
```

is a solution.

But the question stands. Isn't it perfectly all right to use `url_for(...)`?

Comment: No. URLs and file paths are conceptually separate, even though they largely overlap.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith  Ah!! Now we're onto something. But this is a trap even with the more rigorous, say, C++ type declarations. There too `int`s and `std::string`s are unguarded. And so we are either left to be more cautious, or regret that a particular library does not define type wrappers for, in this case, isolating URLs from OS paths.

Answer (score 0):

To setup full path you do not have to use url_for in python.

So, my recomendation is to change you code:

```
from os import path # os needed for folder and file address
# receiving address of a current dirrectory 
script_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
# adding address of your file
filename = script_dir.join('/static/txt/number.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question:

"But the question stands. Isn't it perfectly all right to use url_for(...)?"

`url_for(static, filename='bla.txt')` returns `/static/bla.txt`, and not `static/bla.txt`. Since the starting slash indicates the root of your computer, you try to open a static folder directly at the root of your PC (which is not there).

`url_for(static, filename='bla.txt')[1:]` should work I think, but I think it's a very hacky solution.

So no, it is definity not perfectly alright, and I would definitely not recommend using it. Site routes and folder structure are not the same thing, and should not be intermingled without a good reason (and this is not one).