# Html5 - Download link failed

Tags: android, python, html, heroku

I am trying to download my link from Heroku but I keep getting errors on Heroku server. The link works fine when I used it locally. I am using HTML for the download method. I put the apk file inside my html folder so it should work without directory. Using flask with python.

Here is the code:

```
<p> Download the app here: </p>
<a href="myapp.apk" download="myapp.apk"> Click here to download!</a>
```

Here the errors:

Example: It load to this link (not my real link): https://myapp.herokuapp.com/myapp.apk then.....

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL   manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

and

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What framework are you running on Heroku.

Comment: I'm using Flask on python

Answer (score 0):

Flask doesn't serve static files out of the box, so you may need to tell it what to do. [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask) mentions that you can use [send_from_directory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_from_directory) to do this.