# Why Flask gives 404 for files in the same directory with my application

Tags: python, flask, dreamhost

Let's say I have a domain. Under home directory of the domain I have a text(.txt) file called note.txt. Like below

`https://www.example.com/note.txt`

When I access the url, browser display text string contained inside the file. But when I run a `Flask` under that domain instead of a traditional `html,css,javascript,php` app, server return `404`error even though the file exists in fact at the same location. I can see this from the ftp client.

So why does the server returns `404` error when the site hosts a python app instead of the more traditional `html,css,javascript,php` app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing here is that Flask has [its own URL routing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#routing).

- Python code must be exposed through `app.route` decorator
- Static files, like your `note.txt` can be served through Flask, but they are [often handled by the front end web server (Nginx, Apache) through their configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20648053/315168)

The answer for "why does the server returns 404 error" is that URL routing should be explicit (nothing happens unless you tell it to happen) instead of implicit (everything on the server is exposed by default). Because PHP chose the latter approach, WordPress, Drupal, et. al. traditional PHP sites are getting hacked very easily when they are given to people who don't have the full picture what they are doing. It might be convenient in the beginning, but it is also an open invitation for script kiddies to raid your server.

Comment: So based on what you describe, it should be safe to have a file containing sensitive information like in the aforementioned address(www.example.com/note.txt) if I use framework like ```Flask``` because users cannot access it anyway?

Comment: Yes. If you want to make it available a file containing sensitive information to users you can implement one of various Flask authentication schemes.