# Python Flask - Serving specified page

Tags: python, file, flask, return

EDIT: I found the problem, I simply had a mistyped folder! Anyhow, I thought this would still be useful code if anyone needs it.

Let's say I have a file called test.html and I want it to be returned when I load it on my Flask server, but I don't want to write this for every file I have:

```
@app.route("/test.html")
def atestfile(name=None):
    return open("/home/pi/test/test.html", "r").read()
```

So I thought something like this would work:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catchall(path):
  home = "/home/pi/test/"
  url = home + str(path)
  page = open(url, "r").read()
  return page

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run('0.0.0.0')
```

I know the `def catchall(path):` part could be shortened to one line but I wanted to keep it simple to spot any errors. I get a `500 Internal Server Error` on the web page and no explanation for why in my terminal on my server (Raspbian).

So how could I do something like this?

Comment: Why not use the built-in send_static_file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask

Comment: Had no idea what static file meant.