# cannot load image in flask on ubuntu

Tags: python, flask

I'm just new to Flask and I'm trying to do a project to learn it.I am trying to load a background image for my page and I've tried many ways.But it just gets 404 error .
This is my signup.py file:

```
from flask import Flask , render_template
from database_home import Profile
from flask  import Blueprint
sign_up = Blueprint('sign_up' , __name__,template_folder="/home/ali/Desktop/flasklearn/ccs/templates",static_folder="/home/ali/Desktop/flasklearn/ccs/static/css")
@sign_up.route('/')
def Sign_up():
    return render_template('signup.html')
```

And here in my html file I tried to load the background image and I'm sure that the image exists:

```
<body style='background-image:url("../static/img/abstract-wallpaper-widescreen-az-hd-wallpaper-52-stock-64.jpg")'>
```

Also I've tried this :

```
<body style="background:url {{url_for('sign_up.static',filename='../img/abstract-wallpaper-widescreen-az-hd-wallpaper-52-stock-64.jpg')}}">
```

And also this:

```
<body background="{{url_for('sign_up.static',filename='../images/abstract-wallpaper-widescreen-az-hd-wallpaper-52-stock-64.jpg')}}">
```

And none of these did work.My project structure is like this:

```
project\
        templates\
        views\
        static\
                css\
                img\
```

And I think its good to say that I can load the css files with:

```
<link href="{{url_for('sign_up.static',filename='main3.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Have you configured static file serving?

Comment: How should I exactly do that?I couldn't find any thing for that.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix to your issue:

1 - In `Blueprint` definition, make `static` pointing to the `static` folder instead to `css`:

```
sign_up = Blueprint('sign_up' , __name__,
template_folder="/home/ali/Desktop/flasklearn/ccs/templates",
static_folder="/home/ali/Desktop/flasklearn/ccs/static")
```

2 - Then uring `url_for` get the reference to your image background:

```
<body style='background-image:url("{{url_for('sign_up.static',
filename='img/abstract-wallpaper-widescreen-az-hd-wallpaper-52-stock-64.jpg')}}");'>
```

3 - As for css files:

```
<link href="{{url_for('sign_up.static',filename='css/main3.css')}}"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I've tried this too but 404 error on both css and image files