# Swagger ui is not loading swagger api json

Tags: java, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I have made api documention with the help of `swagger-editor`. Now I want see it graphically with the help of `swagger-ui`. I have deployed my json here https://powerful-escarpment-92284.herokuapp.com/swagger.json

Now When I am trying to access it then I am getting an error

> Failed to load spec.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by setting this header in the response of `swagger.json` file.

```
app.get('/:file(*)', function(req, res, next){
    var file = req.params.file, path = __dirname + '/' + file;

    console.log('.');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    res.download(path);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error in a c# project, due to a problem with a controller I added.
I could get more information by trying to browse to the swagger.json
It turned out I was missing the routing attribute on a controller action.

Answer (score 0):

After many exercises for me apparently, it helped just to serve a file with flask server [[How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask]).  and (important) add "?" to the end of the url, i.e. http://127.0.0.1/js/swagger.json?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is not shown, so I assume if you access the swagger directly via "index.html" or any other way, the URL format must be like this.

```
http://<host>:<port>/<project_name>/_swagger-ui/index.html?url=http://<host>:<port>/<project_name>/<path>/swagger.json
```

like:
http://localhost:8080/counter/_swagger-ui/index.html?url=http://localhost:8080/counter/webapi/swagger.json

I hope, it helps :)