# Error 404 with static pages (Flask Framework)

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I went through many tutorials and everything worked. But I started my own website and I get only error 404 not found.

I downloaded a HTML template and managed to clone the files from Github to PythonAnywhere. Right now the structure of my files is:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7ZqI.png)

**Flask_app.py Code:**

```
from flask import Flask

# set the project root directory as the static folder, you can set others.
app = Flask(flask_app, static_url_path='/home/dubspher/mysite')

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/home/dubspher/mysite/')
def static_file(path):
    return app.send_static_file(index.html)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Should I create another website with templates and use render_template or there's a way I can request a static page with flask?

So far I tried many codes but I don't know what to do with static_url_path

HTML if needed : https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/dubspher/shares/db715c9b9d7c43b7beb4245af23fb56c/

Let me know if I need to add more informations.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask

Comment: Yes this code came directly from this page.

Comment: The @app.route defines the url path that flask is going to be looking for in the request.  So what URL are you requesting?  You would have to be requesting http://yoursite.com/home/dubspher/mysite/ to hit your index page.  Is that what you're requesting or are you requesting http://yoursite.com?  If it's the latter, you want you route to be defined as @app.root('/').  Also, index.html needs to be in quotes.

Comment: Should I change app = Flask(__name__) with flask_app.py ? I can't see any   wsgi or init file, is that a problem to deploy static pages ?

Comment: Sometimes I  also got 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code fixed up to serve up index.html at the root of your site (e.g. http://example.com/):

```
from flask import Flask

# set the project root directory as the static folder, you can set others.
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='/home/dubspher/mysite/')

@app.route('/')
def static_file():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

That assumes that you have an index.html file in your /home/dubspher/mysite directory.

To follow up on your css question, you can get flask to serve up static files generically by passing in a static_url_path to the Flask constructor.  When you do that, any request that comes in matching that static_url_path flask treats as a static file and serves it up based on the static_folder path.  In the sample below, I've set static_url_path to static and the static_folder to /home/dubspher/mysite/.  When a request for http://example.com/static/css/site.css comes in flask will serve up the file /home/dubspher/mysite/css/site.css.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/static", static_folder='/home/dubspher/mysite/')

@app.route('/')
def static_file():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here's an example of referencing a stylesheet at /home/dubspher/mysite/css/site.css from index.html.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/site.css">
</head>
<body>
Hello There
</body>
</html>
```

If you do use the static_url_path, you need to be very careful that everything under your static_folder path is something you want to be accessible.  Flask is going to serve it up as is.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!