# Flask javascript The requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python, flask

when I am trying

python app.py

what I get is a 404 Not Found error saying

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

here is the code inside the file

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///clothes.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.String(50))  # normal, rework, waiting
    current_process = db.Column(db.String(50))
    unique_code = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)


@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()

@app.route('/orders', methods=['GET'])
def get_orders():
    orders = Order.query.all()
    return jsonify([{'id': order.id, 'status': order.status, 'current_process': order.current_process, 'unique_code': order.unique_code} for order in orders])

@app.route('/order/update/<int:order_id>', methods=['POST'])
def update_order(order_id):
    data = request.json
    order = Order.query.get(order_id)
    if not order:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Order not found'}), 404
    order.status = data['status']
    order.current_process = data['current_process']
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'message': 'Order updated'})


@app.route('/order/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_order():
    data = request.json
    new_order = Order(status=data['status'], current_process=data['current_process'], unique_code=data['unique_code'])
    db.session.add(new_order)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'message': 'Order created'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and I also put the index.html in the templates folder which I want to visit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>订单跟踪系统</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>订单跟踪</h1>
    <div id="orders"></div>
    <!-- 此处添加更多的HTML代码来展示和更新订单信息 -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // JavaScript代码来与后端交互
        function loadOrders() {
            axios.get('/orders')
                .then(function (response) {
                    // 处理成功情况
                    console.log(response);
                    // 此处添加代码来展示订单信息
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // 处理错误情况
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }

        loadOrders(); // 载入订单信息
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong?

i want to solve the problem

Comment: What resource is it exactly that is not found? Is it any of your routes like `orders` or `order/create`?

And when does the error occur? When you try to open the browse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 404 with static pages (Flask Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44339692/error-404-with-static-pages-flask-framework) Basically you haven't set up any routes for `index.html` why do you expect flask to serve it?

Comment: axios.get('/orders') => you must use true url server such as 127.0.0.1:5000. I dont see any config what port your server run