# How to serve files in flask to javascript like simplehttpserver does?

Tags: javascript, python, url, flask, gritter

I'm working on a small web application based on Flask and I'd like to use [gritter](https://github.com/jboesch/Gritter) to flash messages, but I get the following error from JS:
**GET http: //127.0.0.1:5000/images/ie-spacer.gif 404 (NOT FOUND)**

I have an images folder, but it doesn't work this way.. this url doesn't exist. I have a static folder, but the script tries to find these files in another folder.. in this case the images folder.

It seems I need some functionality like SimpleHTTPServer has. I also tried AutoIndex and static_url_path without success.

This is the reason I cannot use Flask for [phaser.io](http://phaser.io) as well.
Am I missing something here?:(

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/static/images/ie-spacer.gif`?

Answer (score 0):

On a production system you'd ideally want use another web server to serve static files (like nginx or apache).  It is possible to serve the files from flask directly though:

[How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)