# How can I get this simple Flask website to return robots.txt working?

Tags: flask

I want to have a simple little Flask website that returns a `robots.txt`. Here's what I have so far:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 80)

@app.route("/robots.txt")
def robots_dot_txt():
    return "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /"
```

When I try to access this, I get a 404:

```
213.152.161.130 - -[31/Mar/2018 21:35:01] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/20648053/3990806 Just put robots.txt in your static directory.

Answer (score 6):

it's better to serve your static assets from statics and using the web server,But for your issue, you have to launch the "server" after you defined the routes ... 
so if you move your "run()" at the end of the file, you should be good.

and it's often recommended to inclose it in a if **name**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/robots.txt")
def robots_dot_txt():
    return "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 80)
```

Comment: This works for me, except the `\n` which is not rendered. I had to use <br> instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `robots.txt` file inside the static folder in your project directory. And then set the `static_url_path` when you create your Flask app instance.

```
app
    --__init__.py
    --static
        --robots.txt
    --templates
```

In `app.__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Or you can use `send_from_directory` instead of change the default value of `static_url_path`:

In `app.__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/robots.txt")
def robots():
    return send_from_directory("static", "robots.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```