# python flask how to display image

Tags: python, html, image, flask, display

My logo.jpg which is stored in /home/sally_venka/upload  is not appearing.

This is my file index.html:

```
<body>
<html>    
<form method="GET" action="/show_index1">
<img src="{{ user_image }}" alt="User Image" width="200" height="85">
</body>
</html>
```

This is my file server.py:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER1 = os.path.join('sally_venka', 'upload')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER1 
@app.route('/show_index1',methods=['GET'])
def show_index1():
    full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'logo.jpg')
    render_template("index.html", user_image = full_filename)
    return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could access the image with a static file path.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = '/home/sally_venka/upload/logo.jpg') }}" alt="User Image" width="200" height="85">
```

Comment: While true, this would defeat the purpose of a template because now you can't dynamically change the image displayed from the server side. This is functionally equivalent to just writing `<img src="/home/sally_venka/upload/logo.jpg">`

Comment: This link has the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems here.

1. Your HTML isn't formatted correctly. The `<html>` tag has to be on the first line.
2. Paths. The way you create your file path by joining will result in the string: `sally_venka/upload/logo.jpg`. Your Browser will look at this path relative to wherever your `index.html` is located and will find nothing.

To solve this problem, try replacing

`UPLOAD_FOLDER1 = os.path.join('sally_venka', 'upload')`

with

`UPLOAD_FOLDER1 = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'upload')`

The resulting path (after appending the image filename) will be

`/home/sally_venka/upload/logo.jpg`

Which your browser will be able to find since it isn't a relative, but an absolute path to the file