# Flask - prevent multiple open mysql connections?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have created a flask app with mysql as backend. To initiate DB connection, I have used the following:

```
@app.before_request
def db_connect():    
    try:
        g.db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="ddb",cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,autocommit=True)        
    except Exception as e:                
        print(e)

@app.teardown_request
def db_disconnect(exception=None):
    try:
        if g.db is not None:
            g.db.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Load this in the init_py. But I have checked how many time this mysql is opening and close, Its lot. Because the connection is open and close, even if a css/js file request calls. I calls the g.db in all functions.
How do avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Basically, the code you provided starts a db connection before each request. Each visited url is one request - including retrieved images or stylesheets -, so that's quite often.

**What to do?**

- This [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#storing-data) might be a bit more efficient, but will still create a database at each request. You could check it out.
- Its advisable to route directly to your statics. That will remove a lot of request when the database connection for sure is not required. There are some options to do this with flask itself - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask). I personally use `flask + WSGI`, and add this little script above the line `WSGIDaemonProcess` in my `httpd.conf` file.

  ```
  Alias "/static/" "/home/user/webapps/flask_app/flask_app/static/"
  <Directory "/home/user/webapps/flask_app/flask_app/static/">
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ```
- Do all your views need the db? Otherwise only get the connection on the required views.

  ```
  from functools import wraps
  from flask import g

  def make_db_connection(func): 
      """ decorate views that need a database connection """
      @wraps(func)
      def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
           if 'db' not in g:
               g.db = connect_to_database()
           return func(*args, **kwargs)
       return decorated_function

  @app.teardown_appcontext
  def teardown_db():
      """ close if opened """
      db = g.pop('db', None)
      if db is not None:
          db.close()
  ```
- You can make a small `class` / `API` around your database and cache the most common request. Only works for `select` of course. See this [pretty project](https://pypi.org/project/cached-property/).

  ```
  class Database():

       @threaded_cached_property_with_ttl(ttl=60*60)  # in seconds 
       def some_popular_query():
            connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="", passwd="", db="")
            return connection.get_query()
  ```

**Illustration**

To illustrate, Let's say we have a simple website with `template/main.html`.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"</script>
    <script src="static/style/test.css"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    {{message}}
    <img src="static/img/test.png' />
</body>
```

And `index.py`

```
 from flask import Flask
 app = Flask(__name__)

 @app.route('/')
 def hello_world():
     return render_template('index.html', message='Hello world')
```

With the flask site you describe, you will have one request for the page and template, another request for the stylesheet and another one for the images. That's 3 calls to your database!

Comment: Yes. The example you have shown is correct. It is taking 3 request, 3 open & close to complete the request.

Comment: How are you using flask? With `app.run` or with `WSGI`?

Comment: Currently in app.run. But for htaccess, I'm gonna use WSGI

Comment: Added the snippet I use in my WSGI

Comment: Thanks. I will alter mine.!