# My Python Flask-SocketIO webapp is not running on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, socket.io

I'm having some troubles deploying [this app](https://github.com/shanealynn/async_flask) on Heroku. The code is on a folder, where i created a git using `git init`, added everything to my git and then pushed everything to Heroku before running it.

I generated my `requirements.txt`and my `procfile` looks like this:

```
test: python "application.py" heroku ps:scale web=1
```

But on my webpage nothing will load, i'm assuming because i'm only running the Python part. How can i deploy it so that Heroku will know to run not only my Python script, but also the frontend part with the javascript and index.html files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For development, [you can serve static files with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask).
2. For production, use cloud CDN (like Amazon's or Google's) or add a web-server to your app (Nginx or Apache or whatever).

Comment: For developing i'm using a virtual environment, so that i can test my dynamic webapp on my browser, i'm trying to use Heroku to see what's the outcome when deployed online!

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, is it easier to deploy it and have my app running on a normal page online with CDN rather than with Heroku?

Comment: Heroku is for a dynamic content (i.e. applications, Flask in your case) and CDN is for a static content. They are not mutually exclusive, but are working together. General case: on route '/' Flask returns rendered index.html containing links to JS, CSS and images, that are located on a CDN. Alternative to a CDN would be your own web-server in front of Flask app to serve static on Heroku.