# Serving from Flask I cannot load javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

I am trying to build my first Single Page Application following a tutorial but I cannot load the local javascript file.

**My Python code:**

```
from flask import Flask, current_app


app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return current_app.send_static_file('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**My HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="IndexController">
        <p>{{message}}</p>
    </div>


    <script src="./static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My JavaScript:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('IndexController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'binded ok';
});
```

**The folder structure is:**

```
MyApp
 |-static
 | |-js
 |   |-app.js
 |-index.html
 |-server.py
```

Everything loads okay except for app.js that gives me:

> Request URL: http://localhost:5000/static/js/app.js
>
> Status Code: 404 NOT FOUND

EDIT:
If I open `index.html` directly using the browser `app.js` is loaded. So I think that Flask is creating an issue here.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask

Comment: you should load script as ../../static/js/app.js

Comment: @Yuri it doesn't work. Same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing your JS file like so:

`<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='static/js/app.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: Doesn't work. 404 Not Found once again, with different path.

Comment: Ah, right, I see, sorry. Problem here is that you are serving your index.html as a static file rather than as a template. I'm not sure it you'll be able to refer to your JS file that way.

Comment: So what changes would you recommend in my `server.py`?

Comment: Something like [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#rendering-templates).

Comment: I don't want it to be treated with jinja. Tried to use `send_file()` but same problem.

Comment: Ah, OK. Sorry, then, I can't answer this one.

Answer (score 0):

Create your `App` with `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='', static_url_path='')`