# css is not working with flask using {{url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')}}

Tags: python-3.x, flask

"I'm new to flask framework, so tried to make a simple web app to print hello world then I tried to add some CSS into it but it is not working."

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" {{url_for('static', filename='\css\style.css')}}">
{% block head %} {% endblock %}
```

```
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read This:

> [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)

It will help you now and in the near future when you need to use more files in your HTML page.