# File not found by rendering a html using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am pretty new in using flask and have a basic question: How to provide access to an HTML that is rendered using flask access to static files (such as images). Here my toy example:

I would like to render logo.svg on a website. The Project is structured as

```
Project 
 |
 + -- static
      |
      + -- logo.svg
 + -- templates
      |
      + -- test.html
 + -- run_flask.py
```

test.html looks as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

    <head>

      <title>demo</title>

      <style>
        body {
          font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
          font-size: 14px;
        }

      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="./static/logo.svg" id="logo">
    </body>

</html>
```

and my run_flask-py script contains:

```
import flask
from flask import render_template, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS

app = flask.Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
CORS(app)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/<string:page_name>/')
def render_static(page_name):
    return render_template('%s.html' % page_name)

app.run(port=5001)
```

When a now run the script, the console output is:

> Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

So far so good, but in chrome, http://127.0.0.1:5001/test/ looks like:

[image]

I already looked at [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask) as the problem sounds similar. But I am actually completed confused about how the suggested send_from_directory can help me here.

Can somebody help?

Comment: `<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo.svg') }}" id="logo">` work?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to remove the `static_url_path` argument when you initialise the app:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
```

By default flask will look in the subdirectory `static/` for any static files.  Your directory structure meets this requirement.

As @roganjosh comments, this should then work in the template with:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo.svg') }}" id="logo">
```

As a debug step, you could load `http://127.0.0.1:5001/static/logo.svg` in the browser, and this should display correctly.

---

**UPDATE: re. comment**

> So I guess an empty string defaults to the current app directory or would you need `/` for that

Always good to investigate the actual [source code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/app.py#L169-L174):

> ```
> :param static_url_path: can be used to specify a different path for the
>                         static files on the web.  Defaults to the name
>                         of the `static_folder` folder.
> :param static_folder: the folder with static files that should be served
>                       at `static_url_path`.  Defaults to the ``'static'``
>                       folder in the root path of the application.
> ```

What you were probably looking for was `static_folder` which controls the server based directory.  `static_url_path` effects the URL path which static files are available on the frontend.

Definately easier to just stick with the defaults here, and define neither.

Comment: Nice spot, I missed that bit skimming on my phone. So I guess an empty string defaults to the current app directory or would you need `/` for that (If, for some strange reason, you wanted everything in one directory?)? Can't test atm

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
<img src="../static/logo.svg" id="logo">
```

instead of

```
<img src="./static/logo.svg" id="logo">
```

the `..` points it to the parent directory and the /static enters into the static directory.