# Flask app - Error 404, The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

Tags: python, flask, keras

I am getting "Error 404 -The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." while running the following code:

```
import base64
import numpy as np
import io
from PIL import Image
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

def get_model():
    global model
    model = load_model('xrayV2.h5')
    print("Model loaded!")

def preprocess_image(image, target_size):
    if image.mode !="RGB":
        image = image.convert("RGB")
    image = image.resize(target_size)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

    return image

print("Loading model!!")
get_model()

@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    encoded = message['image']
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    processed_image = preprocess_image(image, target_size=(224, 224))

    prediction = model.predict(processed_image).tolist()

    response = {
        'prediction': {
            'normal': prediction[0][0],
            'pneumonia': prediction[0][1]
        }
    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

Is there anything wrong with the code or with the html, javascript code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>image app</title>
    <style>
        *{
          font-size:30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="image-selector" type="file">
    <button id="predict-button">Predict</button>
    <p style="font-weight:bold">Predictions</p>
    <p>Normal: <span id="normal-prediction"></span></p>
    <p>Pneumonia: <span id="pneumonia-prediction"></span></p>
    <img id="selected-image" src=""/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery=3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      let base64Image;
      $("image-selector").change(function(){
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onLoad = function(e) {
          let dataURL = reader.result;
          $('#selected-image').attr("src", dataURL);
          base64Image = dataURL.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","");
          console.log(base64Image);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL($("image-selector")[0].files[0]);
        $("#normal-prediction").text("");
        $("#pneumonia-prediction").text("");
      });

      $("#predict-button").click(function(event){
        let message = {
          image: base64Image
        }
        console.log(message);
        $.post("http://10.0.0.4:5000/predict", JSON.stringify(message), function(response){
          $("#noraml-prediction").text(response.prediction.normal.toFixed(6));
          $("#pneumonia-prediction").text(response.prediction.pneumonia.toFixed(6));
          console.log(response);
        });
      });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anything wrong in the code? Or with the tensorflow version? i am running Python 3.7.4 and tensorflow 2.1.0

Comment: "/predict" under folder named Static

Answer (score 0):

You've no route to handle returning your HTML page, so create one with method = 'GET' and in that return your HTML file

Comment: @app.route("/static", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    return render_template("predict.html")
Is this how?

Comment: you can use render template but if you have no templates you can just return a static file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask

Comment: Tried to give static folder path
Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.