# Flask displaying images with send_from_directory

Tags: python, flask

My images of plots won't display. I store them separately in "uploads" directory (not static nor its sub).

```py
@app.route('/job/<job_id>')
def get_job(job_id):
    directory_name = db.get(job_id)
    if directory_name is False:
        abort(404)

    return render_template('job.html', directory_name=directory_name)
```

Im passing directory_name to the html:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="{{url_for('send_image', directory_name=directory_name)}}" >
  </body>
</html>
```

Which refers to other view that should browse my directories.

```py
@app.route('/uploads/<directory_name>/plot.png')
def send_image(directory_name, job_id):
    return send_from_directory("uploads", directory_name + "plot.png")
```

However i still get nothing. What I am doing wrong? Is "static" the only directory that flask can handle?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)

Comment: From simple to complex to figure out where the problem is: first, display some image on a fixed HTML, then try to call a specific image.

Answer (score 0):

In the situation that someone needs a suggestion on how to display an image using send_from_directory using Flask this is one way to do it:

```
    from flask import send_from_directory

    return send_from_directory(
        directory = 'static/uploads',
        path      = filename,
        mimetype  = 'application/jpeg' )
```

Where filename is a string that contains the name of the file with the extension .jpeg, for example image1.jpeg (filename="image.jpeg") The image will be downloaded to your local computer and can be viewed.