# Changing the Static folder in a Flask App

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am looking to change which folder is recognized as the main static folder in a flask app while it is running. How could I go about this? Is there a particular config or parameter I can use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask/20648053#20648053

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static') # or rename to your own
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your have a flask app named myblog.py and the following directory structure:

[image: screenshot flask app directory structure]

**assets** is the static directory.
**myblog.py** code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, 
static_url_path='', 
static_folder='app/assets', 
template_folder='app/templates')

@app.route('/')
def index():
      return render_template("index.html")
```

In **index.html** you access the static css file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
```