# How to link index.html (gcloud app deploy)?

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, deployment, gcloud, app.yaml

How would I link the index.html? I am deploying in Google Cloud Platform (using gcloud app deploy). This is so I can make the website with the html. I need a example with a html provided here (any of three html is fine). The index.html is where someone navigates to the root page of your website, what the person sees when clicking or going to the link of the site. My html specifically is just a "hello world" type website. And my files are located in my project (website-deploying-gc). This is the final step to create the site. Here is where the html is located (after getting into the files):

```
jinthemix@cloudshell:~ (website-deploying-gc)$ ls
app.yaml  IMD233  Files  README-cloudshell.txt  README.md  www
jinthemix@cloudshell:~ (website-deploying-gc)$ cd www
jinthemix@cloudshell:~/www (website-deploying-gc)$ ls
Mixs
jinthemix@cloudshell:~/www (website-deploying-gc)$ cd Mixs
jinthemix@cloudshell:~/www/Mixs (website-deploying-gc)$ ls
'Mix 1 (1)'  'Mix 2 (2)'  'Mix 3 (3)'  'Mix 4 (4)'
jinthemix@cloudshell:~/www/Mixs (website-deploying-gc)$ cd 'Mix (1)'
jinthemix@cloudshell:~/www/Mixs/Mix 1 (1) (website-deploying-gc)$ ls
'hello.html (B) (L2).html'  'hello.html (T) (L3).html'  'hello (L1).html'
jinthemix@cloudshell:~/www/Mixs/Mix 1 (1) (website-deploying-gc)$ cd
jinthemix@cloudshell:~ (website-deploying-gc)$ cd
```

Here is a reference link as well, that may provide more information. The site also talks about the index.html. The index.html is basically shows "hello world" to anyone viewing the website: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Your link contains an example. Use that to get started.

Comment: Will take that into account, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) you are using points to deploying a Python 2 application in App Engine. Take into consideration that the programming language itself (Python 2) is [no longer supported by the community since at least January 1st 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) so I'd strongly suggest you to use a similar tutorial for Python 3 (find the link [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/writing-web-service)).

In order to serve static files (e.g. an index.html file that you are referring to) App Engine can handle URLs by executing application code (in the specific tutorial you are following this will consist on modifying your Flask application to serve a static file, as e.g. is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)), or by serving static files uploaded with the code and taking advantage of the [handler element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#handlers_element) defined in your app.yaml file.

The comments within the app.yaml file on the tutorial I linked  for Python 3 explain this in a very understandable way:

```
runtime: python39

handlers:
  # This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
  # directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

  # This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
  # required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
  # the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Notice that you basically define a URL and use an element such as static_dir or static_files to serve that file when a customer lands that specific URL in your application.

Comment: Do you edit -url: /.*?  Here is what the code looks like take a look:

Comment: runtime: python39

handlers:
  # This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
  # directory.
- url: /static/home/jinthemix/www/Mixs/Mix 1 (1)/hello.html (T) (L3).html
  static_dir: static/home/jinthemix/www/Mixs/Mix 1 (1)

  # This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
  # required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
  # the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto

Comment: The example assumes that you have the [following directory structure](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/writing-web-service#structuring_your_web_service_files): notice that your index.html file will be within a template folder (which is a frequent way to design Flask applications, and I'll recommend you to follow that structure). Please edit your answer and post the app.yaml. But for what I see the URL you've defined seems to be related to a directory within your local computer, but this element should define the url in your application.

Comment: I fixed the issue and got the website deploy and it's available now. I used Python2 instead of Python 3 since this website is only a "hello world" site. But I will use information you have provided later on for more sites that require complexity, thanks for the help provided