# How to serve static file from static folder using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have the following Flask app, and I am trying to load a js file from a template:

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory, render_template

# set the project root directory as the static folder, you can set others.
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

@app.route('/js/<path:path>')
def send_js(path):
    return send_from_directory('js', path)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here is the folder:

[image]

My index.html file does load but the js doesn't:

```
<head>
    <script src="/static/js/asynckittens.js"></script>
</head>



  hello world
```

I have tried it as `/js/asynckittens.js`, and even `/asynckittens.js` and nothing will load this file. How can I load a js file in a basic flask server?

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:5000/js/asynckittens.js”.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)

Comment: no thats the link i'm using it isn't working

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, I had to delete the route serving js for flask to find these files:

```
@app.route('/js/<path:path>')
def send_js(path):
    return send_from_directory('js', path)
```

I'm not sure why deleting that made it work but it did