# How can I safely serve Sphinx documentation of a dependency package from my flask app?

Tags: python, flask, python-sphinx

I have developed two projects:

1. A package (projA) with Sphinx documentation
2. A `Flask` app (projB), which utilizes projA and lists it in the `requirements.txt` file.

Therefore, projA would be installed in the virtual environment that coincides with projB.

**My question is:**
How can I safely serve the documentation from the static files in the `/docs/build/html` directory of projA via a route (let's says `/docs`) in projA?

Since projA is installed as a dependency, it would be located in the `/venv/Lib/..` folder. So, I could proxy `/docs` to point to the project folder inside the virtual environment folder, but is that safe? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I wouldn't serve the docs with flask. I'd use a webserver like nginx or apache to serve the static content.

Comment: What if I don't have control over the webserver itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)

Comment: All the suggestions are under the assumption that all static files come from whichever static path is provided during app instantiation. In this case, I have static files that are served from the app's static folder, but **also** have the docs that lie within pkgA inside the venv folder. Since the venv folder is at the root directory of the application, 1) would `send_static_file` work still? 2) would the css and js functionality remain intact for the docs?

Comment: Maybe something like this? `blueprint = Blueprint('docs', __name__, static_url_path='/docs', static_folder='.../venv/Lib/pkgA/docs/build/html')`