# route to directory in flask

Tags: python, flask, directory

I need to expose some icons from a folder in flask like so:

```
PROJECT NAME
>> static
  >> assets
      >> icon-16.png
      >> icon-32.png
      >> icon-64.png
      >> icon-80.png
      >> icon-120.png
      >> logo-filled.png
>> templates
  >> commands.html
  >> index.html
  >> taskpane.html
>> app.py
```

I need to make the `assets` routeable so I can access the png files from urls like this:
`https://pythonlinuxtest.azurewebsites.net/assets/icon-16.png`
`https://pythonlinuxtest.azurewebsites.net/assets/icon-32.png`
`https://pythonlinuxtest.azurewebsites.net/assets/icon-64.png`

Here is what I have in my `app.py` so far:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

# @app.route("/")
# def hello():
#     return "Hello, World!"

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/taskpane.html")
def taskpane():
    return render_template("taskpane.html")

@app.route("/commands.html")
def commands():
    return render_template("commands.html")
```

I am not sure how to add the `assets` directory to the app.py so the png files are accessible.

Comment: The most efficient method is to let the http server to serve static files. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask.helpers import send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/taskpane.html")
def taskpane():
    return render_template("taskpane.html")

@app.route("/commands.html")
def commands():
    return render_template("commands.html")

@app.route("/assets/<file_name>")
def get_image(file_name):
    return send_file(f"./static/assets/{file_name}",mimetype='image/png')
```

Could you try this one

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!! But if anyone knows a better way let me know.

I added the pictures to the app.py using `send_file`

Here is the whole app.py now :)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask.helpers import send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/taskpane.html")
def taskpane():
    return render_template("taskpane.html")

@app.route("/commands.html")
def commands():
    return render_template("commands.html")

@app.route("/assets/icon-16.png")
def icon16():
    return send_file("./static/assets/icon-16.png",mimetype='image/png')

@app.route("/assets/icon-32.png")
def icon32():
    return send_file("./static/assets/icon-32.png",mimetype='image/png')

@app.route("/assets/icon-64.png")
def icon64():
    return send_file("./static/assets/icon-64.png",mimetype='image/png')

@app.route("/assets/icon-80.png")
def icon128():
    return send_file("./static/assets/icon-80.png",mimetype='image/png')

@app.route("/assets/logo-filled.png")
def iconlogofilled():
    return send_file("./static/assets/logo-filled.png",mimetype='image/png')
```

**If anyone knows a more efficient method I will give you credit for the answer. Thanks**