# How to embed a qr code png image in html template page?

Tags: python, html, flask, render, qr-code

I am generating the qr image  using the below code.

```
url="https://www.google.com"
img = qrcode.make(url)
img.save("displayQrInvite.png")
return render_template('invite.html')
```

Below is the html template file.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Scan below qr code image</h1>
    <img src="/displayQrInvite.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Somehow the image is not visible on any of the browsers chrome,edge.c

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the QR code is being generated at a different path.
To resolve this and ensure a consistent display of generated QR codes, it is best to set the output to a static files directory. In addition to the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#static-files), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask) provides some good insight on this.

In your case, what the code would look like is:

```py
# main.py
@app.route("/qr-code")
def display_qr_code():
    url="https://www.google.com"
    img = qrcode.make(url)
    img.save("static/images/displayQrInvite.png")

    return render_template("qr_code.html")
```

```html
<!-- qr_code.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Scan below qr code image</h1>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/displayQrInvite.png') }}"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

The directory structure would look like this:

```
your_project
|- static
|----- images
|- templates
|----- qr_code.html
|- main.py
```