# Flask: static folder failed

Tags: python, flask, routes

I have a problem regarding this simple example can work locally, (index route '/').
However, IT provides port=8000 and a name for me (route '/mywebsite') and
I am facing a problem that after running `python app.py`, I can render the index.html text content but not the image file in static folder.
I found out that the image path will become /aaa.jpg instead of /static/aaa.jpg

If anyone has encounter similar problem, I appreciate any suggestions.

my flask project looks like this:

```
myapp/
    app.py
    static/
        aaa.jpg
    templates/
        index.html
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

templates/index.html

```
This is index page.

<img src="static/aaa.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='aaa.jpg')}}" />
```

does the trick. In Flask you should always use the url_for method to point to static files and to routes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I have tried url_for `<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='aaa.jpg') }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">`  However, only the text "Image" appears but no figure =(

Comment: How does the rest of your index.html look like? I copied your code and if I only have the image tag you provided above in my `index.html` the image is shown.

Comment: I only have two lines in my index.html (shown in my question). I can also render the image on my computer. However, it will fail when I deploy it on a server.

Comment: Ok, sorry my bad. Can you provide clearer information where you try to deploy the app?

Answer (score 0):

check app static folder using by watch app.static_folder

**you can set static folder by:**

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='custom_static_folder')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='aaa.jpg')}}" />
```

You just need this. When using flask always use url_for method to point to files that are in static folder