# 404 Error when accessing styles.css and script.js in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm starting a new Flask project and I seem to be having some bugs.

I've tried searching for help on Google and using AI bots, but the situation still seems unresolvable. I hope you guys can help me with this.

I also tried to put styles.css in static/styles but it still doesn't work. Could it be that my Ubuntu is having problems accessing it?

I really hope you can help me with this. Thank you very much.

Here is tree:

```
├── app.py
├── static
│   └── styles.css
└── templates
    ├── index.html
    └── script.js
```

here is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Description Viewer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="image/*">
    <div id="imageContainer"></div>
    <div id="description"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/get_description', methods=['POST'])
def get_description():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)