# Flask with Docker - Static Files not working

Tags: flask

**Problem:** Static filepaths are not working for me in flask

**Background:** I am deploying flask with docker

**Error Analysis:**

- According to [this link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/tutorial/static/), it is best practice to reference files with "{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}"
- Which is what I am doing

```
<div> <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'nclogo.jpg') }}" style="width:200px"alt="NC logo" /> </div>
```

- I did not change the default foldername for static files, so it should be 'static'
  `... app = Flask(__name__) app.config['DEBUG'] = True ...`
- My file structure is also correct. Files are located directly under the 'static' folder
  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH6mb.png)
- I also double checked in the Docker container. The folders and its contents were created successfully
  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmvcX.png)

Side note:

The css is applied if I render the file direclty without flask with the following tag

```
<div class="header"> <img src="/static/nclogo.jpg" style="width:200px"alt="NC logo" /> </div>
```

Posts I read:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask?rq=2)
- [This](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/tutorial/static/)
- [This](https://sentry.io/answers/serve-static-files-flask/)